# IPv6 not working on a specific computer

Tags: linux, internet, ipv6

I've been having strange issues accessing a particular website (see edits for history) that I eventually narrowed down to IPv6 issues.

It seems my machine cannot establish a TCP connection to any IPv6 address (I also tried google.com with the same results). Another computer running Linux 5.6.19-300.fc32.x86_64 on the same network doesn't seem to be affected. Both are routing through the same router to the same cable modem; the only "obvious" differences are that the affected computer is running kernel 5.7.8-200.fc32.x86_64 and is connected to the router over WiFi rather than wired ethernet. That said, however, I also experience issues when connected over a VPN; between that and the machine that works, the problem is apparently with this specific machine.

Could I have something misconfigured on this machine, or have I stumbled across an OS-level issue? Is there anything I can do to try to narrow this down?

Comment: Have you attempted to contact the staff at `josm.openstreetmap.de` and let them know about the issue? This all seems more like a server software config issue on their side.

Comment: https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/19547? There wasn't an obvious webmaster contact and I'm not sure the abuse@webhost address is appropriate either (or if Hetzner Online GmbH would even know what's going on). The point of asking here was to ask if there's something I can do on my end to work around the problem, e.g. should my networking stack be trying to fall back to the IPv4 address, or why are only some applications affected?

Comment: ...also they're claiming it isn't their fault.

Comment: Have you tried to move affected system to wired ethernet which supposedly works?

Comment: Unfortunately, the machine only has USB-C ports, and I don't have an adapter... and the only machine I have that seems to be using IPv6 does not AFAIK have WiFi.